# NULL when converting VARCHAR to DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use the following statement I just get `NULL` back where it's supposed to return values and undefined fields where the column value is blank.

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE(strdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s') from table`

[image]

My date format is set to `2013-12-11 00:58:00`.

If I select all without converting it (just displaying the VARCHAR as is) then I get this:

[image]

Comment: You have NULL values in field strdate.

Comment: You are using the same code (`%m`) for months and minutes. That can't be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code for minutes is `%i` not `%m`:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(strdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
from (select '2013-12-11 00:58:00' as strdate) t
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s'` - `%m` can't stand for month **and** minute. IIRC `%m` is correct for them month, and `%i` is what you want for the minute.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

> If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning.

What this means is that the value of `strdate` does not match the format pattern of `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s'` (also note the format string needs to follow the same set up and rules listed under [DATE_FORMAT in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format))

### You should always store date[time] values in their appropriate data types. A string that looks like a date is still a string and *NOT* a date.

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT YOUR ANSWER ;)

Comment: @Tony every reason to. This is basic stuff that will get lost if Askers just see how to fix the immediate problem (the invalid format string) instead of the core, underlying issue, of storing dates as strings. ;)